# Setting breakpoints for data with scale_fill_brewer() function in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a map (choropleth) as described on the [ggplot2 wiki](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles). Everything works like a charm, except that I am running into an issue mapping a continuous value to the polygon fill color via the scale_fill_brewer() function.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996513/change-colour-scheme-for-ggplot-geom-polygon-in-r) describes the problem I'm having. As in the answer, my workaround has been to pre-cut my data into bins using the gtools quantcut() function:

**UPDATE: This first example is actually the right way to do this**

```
require(gtools) # needed for quantcut()

...

fill_factor <- quantcut(fill_continuous, q=seq(0,1,by=0.25))
ggplot(mydata) + 
aes(long,lat,group=group,fill=fill_factor) +
geom_polygon() +
scale_fill_brewer(name="mybins", palette="PuOr")
```

This works, however, I feel like I should be able to skip the step of pre-cutting my data and do something like this with the breaks option:

```
ggplot(mydata) +
aes(long,lat,group=group,fill=fill_continuous) +
geom_polygon() +
scale_fill_brewer(names="mybins", palette="PuOr", breaks=quantile(fill_continuous))
```

But this doesn't work. Instead I get an error something like:

> Continuous variable (composite score) supplied to discrete scale_brewer.

Have I misunderstood the purpose of the "breaks" option? Or is breaks broken?

Comment: As the error says `scale_fill_brewer` is for discrete data, not continuous.

Comment: Thanks, Hadley--for the answer and for writing the package. I think I was assuming that continuous data + breaks = discrete.

Does that mean that my first example (pre-cutting my continuous data) is the 'right' way to do this?

Comment: Yes.  Legends are no different to axes - setting breaks on an axis doesn't make the data discrete, it just moves the tick marks around.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. I can't believe how many questions about ggplot2 you answer--you get my vote for open source MVP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hadley explains, the breaks option moves the ticks, but does not make the data continuous. Therefore pre-cutting the data as per the first example in the question is the right way to use the scale_fill_brewer command.

Answer (score 4):

A major issue with pre-cutting continuous data is that there are three pieces of information used at different points in the code:

- The Brewer palette -- determines the maximum number of colors available
- The number of break points (or the bin width) -- has to be specified with the data
- The actual data to be plotted -- influences the choice of the Brewer palette (sequential/diverging)

A true vicious circle. This can be broken by providing a function that accepts the data and the palette, automatically derives the number of break points and returns an object that can be added to the `ggplot` object. Something along the following lines:

```
fill_brewer <- function(fill, palette) {
  require(RColorBrewer)
  n <- brewer.pal.info$maxcolors[palette == rownames(brewer.pal.info)]
  discrete.fill <- call("quantcut", match.call()$fill, q=seq(0, 1, length.out=n))
  list(
    do.call(aes, list(fill=discrete.fill)),
    scale_fill_brewer(palette=palette)
  )
}
```

Use it like this:

```
ggplot(mydata) + aes(long,lat,group=group) + geom_polygon() +
  fill_brewer(fill=fill_continuous, palette="PuOr")
```

Comment: Seems great but I get "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale".