# Format labels produced by cut() as percentages

Tags: r

I need to apply `cut` on a continuous variable to show it with a Brewer color scale in ggplot2, as in [Setting breakpoints for data with scale_fill_brewer() function in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6738085/946850). The continuous variable is a relative difference, and I'd like to format the data as "18.2 %" instead of "0.182". Is there an easy way to achieve this?

```
x <- runif(100)
levels(cut(x, breaks=10))

[1] "(0.0223,0.12]" "(0.12,0.218]"  "(0.218,0.315]" "(0.315,0.413]"
[5] "(0.413,0.511]" "(0.511,0.608]" "(0.608,0.706]" "(0.706,0.804]"
[9] "(0.804,0.901]" "(0.901,0.999]"
```

I'd like, e.g., the first level to appear as `(2.23 %, 12 %]`. Is there a better alternative to `cut`?

Comment: +1 for clear question title, reproducible code and clear goal of what is desired. People could learn from this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new [{santoku} package](https://hughjonesd.github.io/santoku/) now offers a way to do this in the development version:

```r
library(santoku)

set.seed(20200607)
x <- runif(20)

chop_evenly(x, 10, labels = lbl_intervals(fmt = percent))
#>  [1] [33.13%, 42.11%) [60.08%, 69.06%) [69.06%, 78.04%) [69.06%, 78.04%)
#>  [5] [87.02%, 96%]    [6.193%, 15.17%) [15.17%, 24.15%) [6.193%, 15.17%)
#>  [9] [33.13%, 42.11%) [6.193%, 15.17%) [87.02%, 96%]    [51.1%, 60.08%) 
#> [13] [42.11%, 51.1%)  [6.193%, 15.17%) [42.11%, 51.1%)  [6.193%, 15.17%)
#> [17] [6.193%, 15.17%) [69.06%, 78.04%) [78.04%, 87.02%) [87.02%, 96%]   
#> 9 Levels: [6.193%, 15.17%) [15.17%, 24.15%) ... [87.02%, 96%]
tab_evenly(x, 10, labels = lbl_intervals(fmt = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 0.1)))
#> x
#>  [6.2%, 15.2%) [15.2%, 24.2%) [33.1%, 42.1%) [42.1%, 51.1%) [51.1%, 60.1%) 
#>              6              1              2              2              1 
#> [60.1%, 69.1%) [69.1%, 78.0%) [78.0%, 87.0%) [87.0%, 96.0%] 
#>              1              3              1              3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 18):

I have implemented [`cut_format()`](http://krlmlr.github.io/kimisc/reference/cut_format.html) in version 0.2-3 of my `kimisc` package, version 0.3 is on CRAN now.

```
# devtools::install_github("krlmlr/kimisc")
x <- seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.2)

breaks <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.25)

cut(x, breaks)
## [1] (0,0.25]   (0.25,0.5] (0.25,0.5] (0.5,0.75] (0.75,1]  
## Levels: (0,0.25] (0.25,0.5] (0.5,0.75] (0.75,1]

cut_format(x, breaks, format_fun = scales::percent)
## [1] (0%, 25%]   (25%, 50%]  (25%, 50%]  (50%, 75%]  (75%, 100%]
## Levels: (0%, 25%] (25%, 50%] (50%, 75%] (75%, 100%]
```

It's still not perfect, passing the number of breaks (as in the original example) doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 12):

Use `gsub` with some regex after multiplying your original data by 100:

```
gsub("([0-9.]+)","\\1%",levels(cut(x*100,breaks=10)))
 [1] "(0.449%,10.4%]" "(10.4%,20.3%]"  "(20.3%,30.2%]"  "(30.2%,40.2%]"  "(40.2%,50.1%]"  "(50.1%,60%]"    "(60%,69.9%]"    "(69.9%,79.9%]"  "(79.9%,89.8%]"  "(89.8%,99.7%]"
```

Comment: Just hacked a similar thing, too. I thought there must be a better way :-)

Comment: I think it's probably the easiest way since, the multiply by 100 step would be hard to do once you've created the text labels.

Comment: I was thinking about something along `cut(x, labels=function(lo, hi) paste0(...))`...

Comment: the cleanest solution to date for people like me who don't want to use a new package for every little hiccup

Answer (score 7):

Why not copy the code for `cut.default` and create your own version with modified levels? See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4593967).

Two lines were changed:

Line 22: `ch.br <- formatC(breaks, digits = dig, width = 1)` changed to `ch.br <- formatC(breaks*100, digits = dig, width = 1)`.

Line 29: `else "[", ch.br[-nb], ",", ch.br[-1L], if (right)` changed to `else "[", ch.br[-nb], "%, ", ch.br[-1L], "%", if (right)`

The rest is the same. And here it is in action:

```
library(devtools)
source_gist(4593967)

set.seed(1)
x <- runif(100)
levels(cut2(x, breaks=10))
#  [1] "(1.24%, 11%]"   "(11%, 20.9%]"   "(20.9%, 30.7%]" "(30.7%, 40.5%]" "(40.5%, 50.3%]"
#  [6] "(50.3%, 60.1%]" "(60.1%, 69.9%]" "(69.9%, 79.7%]" "(79.7%, 89.5%]" "(89.5%, 99.3%]"
```

Comment: I have managed to do it using a one-line change only: https://gist.github.com/4594243. However, this loses the space after the `,`, for which a second parameter to `cut` would be required. Will propose extending R's `cut.default` if nothing else comes up.

Answer (score 4):

A new answer to an oldish question.

You could use the `label` argument to pass a function to format the labels. I will use `gsubfn` and `scales::percent`

```
library(gsubfn)
library(scales)
pcut <- function(x) gsubfn('\\d\\.\\d+', function(x) percent(as.numeric(x)),xx)
d <- data.frame(x=runif(100))

ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=seq_along(x))) + 
 geom_point(aes(colour = cut(x, breaks = 10))) + 
 scale_colour_brewer(name = 'x', palette = 'Spectral', label = pcut)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, that is indeed another nice option. I have just posted my thoughts about the complications with binning data here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17438591/946850. The main issue is that the data, the cutting algorithm, the number of breaks and the palette all influence each other, but are scattered around several different function calls. Shouldn't this be part of an R package, what do you think?

Comment: @krlmlr Yes, but I usually go down the `scale_colour_gradientn` road eg `ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=seq_along(x))) + geom_point(aes(colour = x)) + 
scale_colour_gradientn(colours = brewer.pal('Spectral',n=10), label = percent)` -- which will kill some kittens.

Comment: Yes, and of course there's even a [pull request](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/439) that addresses this, which then must be sort of a kitten killer machine. I was considering using that, but now I find the discretization/cutting/binning approach clearer. It's just that, currently, there seems to be no neat notation for this.

Answer (score 2):

My package `cutr` does very similar things to @krlmlr's function (that I didn't know up until now).

`cutf` is just `cut` with a `format_fun` argument, and `...` which is passed to `format_fun`, not `cut` as in`cut_format`.

`smart_cut` has more features and different defaults :

```
devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/cutr")
library(cutr)

x <- seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.2)
breaks <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.25)

cutf(x, breaks, format_fun = scales::percent)
# [1] (0%,25%]   (25%,50%]  (25%,50%]  (50%,75%]  (75%,100%]
# Levels: (0%,25%] (25%,50%] (50%,75%] (75%,100%]

smart_cut(x, breaks, format_fun = scales::percent,simplify = F, closed = "right")
# [1] [0%,25%]   (25%,50%]  (25%,50%]  (50%,75%]  (75%,100%]
# Levels: [0%,25%] < (25%,50%] < (50%,75%] < (75%,100%]
```

`Hmisc::cut2` now also has a `formatfun` argument :

```
library(Hmisc)
Hmisc::cut2(x, breaks, formatfun = scales::percent)
# [1] [0%,25%)   [25%,50%)  [50%,75%)  [50%,75%)  [75%,100%]
# Levels: [0%,25%) [25%,50%) [50%,75%) [75%,100%]
```

Comment: Happy to retire my `cut_format()` once _cutr_ is on CRAN.