# How to remove E notation from label cut intervals and replace with shorthand labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Looking to pass either `label_number_si()` or something like it to label cut intervals with SI units ("k" for thousand, etc.).

```
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(test_x=1:1e5, test_y=1) %>% 
  mutate(label_cut=cut_width(test_x,1e4, boundary = 0))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_col(aes(test_x,label_cut)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = label_number_si())
```

[image]

Comment: Use the syntax `labels = label_number_si`—the argument should be a function *to call*, not the function call *itself*. It's a sometimes tricky distinction

Comment: I want to label the numbers on the y axis, the function works for the continuous x axis.

Comment: Oh, got it. You can supply labels to `cut_width`, which will be passed on to the base `cut`, but I think that might require manually (or with `paste`, etc) creating labels. I actually have to do this a lot for work with intervals that I won't know beforehand, so I wrote a function [here](https://github.com/camille-s/camiller/blob/main/R/brk_labels.R) that splits apart the interval endpoints, formats the numbers based on some specification, and pastes them back together

Comment: I don't *quite* want to mark this as a duplicate, but a similar question with very good answers on labeling is here https://stackoverflow.com/q/14456371/5325862

Comment: Yeah, those don't address this question so I think this is fine.

Comment: Maybe you could be more clear on what labels you want exactly. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17438610/5325862) from the linked post creates a function that identifies interval endpoints from the labels and reformats those numbers with a function from `scales`, and passes that function as the `labels` argument to a ggplot scale (in that case, color rather than y). That should get something like `"(10k,20k]"` instead of `"(1e+04,2e+04]"`. Does that not cover it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to write up some custom functions to break up the interval:

```
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)

SI_format <- function(x) {
  case_when(
    x < 1e3 ~ as.character(x),
    x < 1e6 ~ paste0(as.character(x/1e3), "K"),
    x < 1e9 ~ paste0(as.character(x/1e6), "M"),
    x < 1e12 ~ paste0(as.character(x/1e9), "B"),
    x < 1e15 ~ paste0(as.character(x/1e12), "T"),
    TRUE ~ "..."
  )
}

pretty_labels <- function(x) {

first_bracket <- str_extract(x,"^.") 
last_bracket <- str_extract(x,".$")
first_number <- SI_format(as.numeric(str_extract(x,"(\\d+)")))
last_number <- SI_format(as.numeric(str_extract(x,"(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)")))

new_label <- paste0(first_bracket,first_number,",",last_number,last_bracket)
return(new_label)
}

dat <- data.frame(test_x=c(0,1, 10, 1e2,1e3,1e4,1e5,1e6), test_y=1) %>% 
  mutate(label_cut=cut_width(test_x,1e3, boundary = 0, dig.lab=10))

levels(dat$label_cut) <- pretty_labels(levels(dat$label_cut))

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_col(aes(test_x,label_cut)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = label_number_si())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way with my `santoku` package:

```r
library(santoku)
dat$label_cut <- chop_width(
                   dat$test_x, 
                   1e4, 
                   labels = lbl_intervals(fmt = scales::label_number_si())
                 )
```