# label cut() output with hyphen

Tags: r, label

I want a way to automatically edit the label output from the following `cut`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(0:50, 200, replace = T))
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(a_cut = cut(a, 
                     breaks = c(0:9, seq(10, 40, by = 5), Inf), include.lowest = FALSE,
                           right = FALSE))
tabyl(df, a_cut)
#     a_cut  n percent
#     [0,1)  5   0.025
#     [1,2)  3   0.015
#     [2,3)  1   0.005
#     [3,4)  1   0.005
#     [4,5)  0   0.000
#     [5,6)  7   0.035
#     [6,7)  3   0.015
#     [7,8)  0   0.000
#     [8,9)  3   0.015
#    [9,10)  4   0.020
#   [10,15) 15   0.075
#   [15,20) 17   0.085
#   [20,25) 24   0.120
#   [25,30) 17   0.085
#   [30,35) 21   0.105
#   [35,40) 27   0.135
#  [40,Inf) 52   0.260
```

into the following cut labels (`a_cut`):

```
# a_cut   n percent
#     0   5   0.025
#     1   3   0.015
#     2   1   0.005
#     3   1   0.005
#     4   0   0.000
#     5   7   0.035
#     6   3   0.015
#     7   0   0.000
#     8   3   0.015
#     9   4   0.020
# 10-14  15   0.075
# 15-19  17   0.085
# 20-24  24   0.120
# 25-29  17   0.085
# 30-34  21   0.105
# 35-39  27   0.135
# 40+    52   0.260
```

I think the [cutr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674078/4083743) or [kimisc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34951557/4083743) package could do it but I cant figure out the correct configuration.

```
#e.g., comes close
kimisc::cut_format(df$a, c(1:9, seq(10, 40, by = 5)), sep = "-", paren = c("", "", "", ""))
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `labels` argument to `cut`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(0:50, 200, replace = T))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(a_cut = cut(a, 
                     breaks = c(0:9, seq(10, 40, by = 5), Inf), 
                     labels = c(0:9, paste(2:7 * 5, 2:7 * 5 + 4, sep = '-'),
                                '40+'),
                     include.lowest = FALSE,
                     right = FALSE))

tabyl(df, a_cut)
#>  a_cut  n percent
#>      0  5   0.025
#>      1  3   0.015
#>      2  1   0.005
#>      3  1   0.005
#>      4  0   0.000
#>      5  7   0.035
#>      6  3   0.015
#>      7  0   0.000
#>      8  3   0.015
#>      9  4   0.020
#>  10-14 15   0.075
#>  15-19 17   0.085
#>  20-24 24   0.120
#>  25-29 17   0.085
#>  30-34 21   0.105
#>  35-39 27   0.135
#>    40+ 52   0.260
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own function and apply it in the `labels` parameter:

```r
#Create function
label_interval <- function(breaks){
  ifelse(diff(breaks) == 1, breaks, paste0(breaks[-length(breaks)], "-", breaks[-1] - 1))
}

#Breaks
my_breaks = c(0:9, seq(10, 40, by = 5), Inf)

df %>% 
  mutate(a_cut = cut(a, breaks = my_breaks, labels = label_interval(my_breaks),
                     include.lowest = FALSE, right = FALSE)) %>%
  tabyl(a_cut)

 #  a_cut  n percent
 #      0  5   0.025
 #      1  3   0.015
 #      2  1   0.005
 #      3  1   0.005
 #      4  0   0.000
 #      5  7   0.035
 #      6  3   0.015
 #      7  0   0.000
 #      8  3   0.015
 #      9  4   0.020
 #  10-14 15   0.075
 #  15-19 17   0.085
 #  20-24 24   0.120
 #  25-29 17   0.085
 #  30-34 21   0.105
 #  35-39 27   0.135
 # 40-Inf 52   0.260
```

Comment: thanks (its just missing `40+` in the final row!)